# Experiment to see if speed of light is different in different directions

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation

Clock/laser/detector A synced with B, moved a set distance from eachother, which of course unsyncs them because of time dialation. Both clocks are still running with different times shown on their faces, a pulse from A is sent and logged on A as $A_1$, arrives at B and is logged on B as $B_1$.
B after any amount of time will (won't change the results) then send a pulse logging its time as $B_2$. A recieves the pulse, logs the time as $A_2$.

We then substract $B_1$ from $A_1$ to get the difference in time (this time does not indicate any velocity given; we don't know the amount of time dialation). We also do this for $A_2$, $B_2$. After we get the diffrence in times we subtract those differences from each other: $|A_1-B_1|-|A_2-B_2|$. If this value is greater or less than 0, then the speed of light is different in different directions.

I'm asking if this experiment would prove it, or I'm just a big dummy and missed something somewhere?

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but what is your question?  Are you perhaps asking if this is possible?

Comment: I'm asking if this experiment would prove it, or I'm just a big dummy and missed something somewhere.

Comment: LOL.  We're all big dummies.  Just some of us are more aware of it than others!  May I recommend adding your comment (or at least part of it)  to the end of your post?  Then you'll have a question! :)

Comment: There you go!  Looks good.  Upvoted, because anyone who recognizes they might be a big dummy is deserving of an upvote, IMO.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, suppose A and B are a light-minute apart, and Clock B is 30 minutes ahead of Clock A, the two clocks being stationary relative to each other.

Let's start by assuming the speed of light is constant in every direction.

Clock A sends a light pulse at 12:00.

Clock B receives it a minute later at 12.31 B-time.

Clock B returns a pulse at 13:00 B time.

Clock A receives the pulse a minute later at 12:31 A-time.

There are several problems here that need to be worked out. Firstly, the time difference one way is 29 minutes and the other way is 31 minutes, so they are not equal, so according to your formula the speed of light is not the same in every direction- that's clearly wrong, because we explicitly assumed c was constant when we worked out the travel times. That in itself doesn't invalidate your idea, because you could work-out what was going on if you knew clock B was exactly thirty minutes ahead, so you could say that if the time difference is not the two minutes we predicted by assuming c was constant, then c isn't constant.

The question is, how would you know that Clock B was 30 minutes ahead, and how would you know if was a light minute away if you didn't assume the speed of light was constant in the first place? Indeed, how would you even know that the clocks were stationary relative to each other?

You can try to imagine an experiment in which you do it all in a lab with A and B a light-nanosecond apart, and using atomic clocks etc, but you will find the same problem. Even if you used a ruler to fix the distance, you will find that the definition of a meter is defined as the distance travelled by light in a given time, so you would be back to square one.

ADDENDUM

To try to make it more clear, the difference |1−1|−|2−2| is never zero- it will always give you a result which is the round trip time.

Take the example of A sending a pulse at 12:00 which takes a minute to travel to B which is 30 minutes ahead at 12:31, where it is immediately bounced back to A where it returns at 12:02. If you plug in the numbers you will see that you get 31-29=2.

OK, now suppose the speed of light is infinite on the outward trip and 0.5c on the return. What you will now get is the light leaving A at 12:00, arriving instantaneously at B where the clock shows 12.30, and being sent straight back to arrive at A at 12:02. Plug in the numbers again to your formula and you will get 30-28=2.

So in both cases, the formula you propose gives the answer 2, so it is not capable of detecting the difference in the speed of light in each direction.

.

Comment: The whole point of the experiment is the assumption that I do not know the one way speed of light. If I'm comparing the times of A to B, vs B to A and seeing if there is a difference (with no knowledge of a 30 minute gap or some N minute gap). Now sets you stated A sends pulse at 12:00 one light minute away and arrives at B at 12:31, but then 12:31 pulse from B arrives at A at 13:00, this is 29-31, with absolute difference of 2. with no assumption of the speed of light I think this works fine, but sets you have already stated a constant speed of light but then changed the times it does not.

Comment: If you want to assume clock B is ahead of Clock A by 30 minutes and a 1 light minute gap, pulse from A at 12:00 and arrrives at B at 12:31, and B to A is 13:00 then conclusion light is faster/slower in different directions, if A to B is 12:00-12:31, and B to A is 12:31-13:02 then light moves the same speed in all directions (which is the only thing I'm concerned about.

Comment: But you can't tell if A and B are stationary? How would you know whether the difference wasn't just because they've drifted further apart?

Comment: I've added an extra section to try to make it more clear.

Comment: It's because in one direction the difference in readings gives you the offset between the clocks plus the travel time, while in the other direction it gives you the offset minus the travel time.

Answer (score 0):

There have been experiments to test if the speed of light depends on direction.

The Michelson-Morley experiment

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment_(1887)

used interference of light to try and detect a change in the light speed in different directions, when the apparatus was turned on a trough of mercury.  The length of the 'arms' of the experiment were regarded as unchanged when the apparatus was turned.  Any slight difference originally, in the arm lengths wouldn't matter, as they were looking for a change of the speed of light with direction.

Your experiment has the difficulty of finding exactly how far the 'arms' are apart.  If that isn't known, you'd need a way to turn the experiment to look for changes - and you'd probably end up designing an experiment similar to the one in the link.